# Unwanted delay between button press and game start

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, lag

I'm making a game with sprite kit that has a start button, and on press it loads the game scene. As this game is just testing purposes, I am doing it all in 1 scene.

**Edit**

This code solved my problem:

```
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"StartButton"]) {

        NSLog(@"Start Pressed");
        [self load];


        SKTextureAtlas *artAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"assets"];
        [artAtlas preloadWithCompletionHandler:^{

            NSLog(@"All loaded");

            //Any other things
```

Comment: Post the code that you suspect is causing the delay. Most likely it will be loading resources. Look into the preload functions of SKTexture(Atlas) and related questions here.

Comment: I have the images in a texture atlas, how could I load them more efficiently at the start?

Comment: 1) Player touches start button. 2) Display label stating something like "loading". 3) Load game assets such as textures, sounds, etc. 4) When all assets are loaded, start game.  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTextureAtlas/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013028-CH1-SW2

Comment: Thanks a bunch you guys this is a great help :). Thank you so much